# ddnss linking problem

Tags: links

I'm facing an issue with ddnss.org linking to my wordpress. The main page is loading from outside my home, however backend and sub-pages prefix url with my internal ip.

F.e.
http://mycoolDomainName.ddnss.org/  will change to http://192.168.123.45/mySubpage?parameters

Here is my setup:

Server with headless Ubuntu on Fritzbox (version numbers should not matter here)

Fritzbox automatically updates ddnss, this is great.
Unfortunately, ddnss only seems to allow plain http connections (80) instead of https (443).

Wordpress 5.7 installed with PHP8 and mysql, having a subfolder inside my wordpress root with a PHPmyadmin stack running. Database works, users are created, everything has a password. All folders have the right user/group permissions.

How can I fix this issue?

NOTE:

Since I wanted to be able to have multi-page on a single server with staging, I symlinked inside `/var/www/html/ProjectXYZ` to `/home/user/projectXYZ/`. Could this be a problem? Note, in my home-network I can access everything just fine.

Also, I think it would not be that bad to only be able to access `wp-admin` just from inside my home-network, so would it be possible to leave the backend with this currently "broken" setup and just have sub-pages link correctly?

Comment: What are you using for the site URL and blog URL in Settings, General? Is that the ddnss.org address or your IP address?

Comment: And if DDNSS is just a DNS provider not a reverse web proxy then it's your server or router that's only allowing HTTP not HTTPS.

Comment: good hint, will check when I'm back from work and will also double-check the forwarding and router-config

Comment: if WP is configured to use that IP address as its URL, it will redirect to it. Note that questions here are written in markdown not HTML